# How to write "smart" "phone" in British English?

Tags: british-english, writing-style

In British English, how do you write *smartphone*? Is it:

- Smart phone
- Smart-phone
- Smartphone

Comment: *Smartphone*, this is a more commonly used version.

Comment: Would anyone write sam-sung or sam sung!? No. Smartphone is a term in itself. *Smart phone* is term for a phone that the speaker thinks is smart.

Comment: See Google Books  results for BrE usage: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=smart+phone%2Csmartphone&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csmart%20phone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csmartphone%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @user3382203 — "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments."

Answer (score 1):

Nothing could be more British than the BBC (British Broadcasting Corporation). If you go to their [website](http://www.bbc.co.uk) and start typing “smart” it autocompletes to:

> Smartphones

And if you follow the link to articles, that is the form used.

If you can bring yourself to do so, you could also search in the British gutter press and find the same thing. The name of the rag is ‘The Sun’ and searching for “smartphone” gave me 1045 results, which, judging by the first page, seemed to use this form. (Must delete from my browser history now.)